# Accessing Application variable that hold a dictionary object in C#

Tags: c#, variables, dictionary, for-loop

I have created a Dictionary in Application scope, but I'm not sure how to correctly access it in another page.

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    Application["PaginationTable"] = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    Dictionary<int, int> dictPagination = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    //fill dict
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        etc
    }

    Application["PaginationTable"] = dictPagination;

}
```

In myotherpage.cs

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in Application["PaginationTable"])
  {

      Response.Write(pair.Key +" :: " + pair.Value  + "<br>");
      etc
  }
```

The error generated is:
"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

The gist is that I need to create a Dictionary to hold a table of value/pair data that will not change and will need accessing/compared by different sections of the website.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Application` can store many different types, it has to store them as `Object`, the parent class all types are inherited from. You need to cast the `Application["PaginationTable"]` to the correct type, i.e. `Dictionary<int, int>` that foreach can operate on. i.e.:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in (Dictionary<int, int>)Application["PaginationTable"])
```

---

Note that to save typing `KeyValuePair<int, int>` can be replaced with `var`, as the compiler can work out the correct type at compile time.

---

Also note that the line

```
Application["PaginationTable"] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

is redundant as you just assign another object to it lower down.

Comment: Good, glad i can help. If my answer was the most helpful, be sure to click the green 'tick' next to it.

Answer (score 2):

Everything stored as an Application variable (or Session varible) is of type **Object**.

I order to read that application variable as a Dictionary object, just cast that object to it:

```
 foreach (var pair in (Dictionary<int, int>)Application["PaginationTable"])
```